# Parts of geometry disappearing in QGIS export to Illustrator PDF?

Tags: qgis, polygon, print-composer, illustrator, missing-data

I'm having this issue with certain polygons when I export to PDF. Everything looks fine in QGIS, everything fine in print composer, everything fine in the PDF as viewed in Preview or Adobe Reader. When I open the PDF in Illustrator to edit, a section of the outline of a certain polygon completely disappears. I'm using QGIS Brighton on a Mac, but also tried in Chugiak on a PC and have had the same exact problems with the same polygons (I'm giving just one example, but it's happened with multiple files). I'm stumped.

Anyone know how to fix this?

All geometry intact (in QGIS and PDF)
[image: What it looks like in QGIS]

From Illustrator, part of the line of the main shape missing (fill switches to complete shape on other side of existing line)
[image: What it looks like as a PDF]

Comment: Illustator has a display limit around 60,000 vertices per feature you need to split lines or generalise your data down before export.

Answer (score 5):

As @Mapperz says:

> Illustrator has a display limit around 60,000 vertices per feature you
>   need to split lines or generalise your data down before export.

You can generalise the lines down before exporting and entering in to Illustrator. You can generalise lines with `Vector > Geometry Tools > Simplify Geometries`